# Overloading operator>> C++

Tags: c++

I have a problem with `operator>>` when I try to use it in my class String. I need to make a string from keyboard, but all my tries make fails. Help me, please.

When I try to turn in this code, I always have a crash.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

class myString
{
public:

    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const myString& other);
    friend std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& in, myString& other);

    myString()
    {
        str = nullptr;
        length = 0;
    }

    myString(const char* str)
    {

        length = strlen(str);

        this->str = new char[length + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            this->str[i] = str[i];
        }

        this->str[length] = '\0';

    }

    ~myString()
    {
        delete[] this->str;
    }

    myString(const myString& other)
    {
        length = strlen(other.str);
        this->str = new char[length + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            this->str[i] = other.str[i];
        }

        this->str[length] = '\0';
    }

    myString& operator =(const myString& other)
    {

        if (this->str != nullptr)
        {
            delete[] str;
        }

        length = strlen(other.str);
        this->str = new char[length + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            this->str[i] = other.str[i];
        }

        this->str[length] = '\0';

        return *this;

    }
    myString& operator =(const char* other)
    {

        if (this->str != nullptr)
        {
            delete[] str;
        }

        length = strlen(other);
        this->str = new char[length + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            this->str[i] = other[i];
        }

        this->str[length] = '\0';

        return *this;

    }

    myString& operator +=(myString const& other) {
        return (this->operator=(this->operator+(other)));
    }

    myString operator +(const myString& other)
    {

        myString newStr;

        int thisLength = strlen(this->str);
        int otherLength = strlen(other.str);

        newStr.length = thisLength + otherLength;

        newStr.str = new char[thisLength + otherLength + 1];

        int i = 0;
        for (; i < thisLength; i++)
        {
            newStr.str[i] = this->str[i];
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < otherLength; j++, i++)
        {
            newStr.str[i] = other.str[j];
        }

        newStr.str[thisLength + otherLength] = '\0';

        return newStr;
    }

    void Print()
    {
        cout << str;
    }

    int Length()
    {
        return length;
    }

    bool operator ==(const myString& other)
    {
        if (this->length != other.length)
        {
            return false;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < this->length; i++)
        {
            if (this->str[i] != other.str[i])
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    bool operator !=(const myString& other)
    {
        return !(this->operator==(other));
    }

    char& operator [](int index)
    {
        return this->str[index];
    }

private:
    char* str;
    int length;

};

ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const myString& other)
{
    out << other.str;

    return out;
}

istream& operator >> (istream& in, myString& other)
{
    in.getline(other.str, sizeof(other.str));
    return in;
}

int main()
{

    myString str_3;
    cin >> str_3;
    cout << str_3;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Off-topic, but this: `myString& operator +=(myString const& other) { return (this->operator=(this->operator+(other))); }` -- I suggest you implement `operator +=` fully, and then write `operator +` in terms of `operator +=`.  Otherwise that line of code you have written is really confusing.

Comment: `sizeof(other.str)` during `in.getline(other.str, sizeof(other.str));` is always the size of a pointer.

Comment: Also your `operator =` is flawed in multiple ways.  Try this: `myString s1;...s1 = s1;` -- you will see your code fail.  Even if you fix that, the other flaw is that you `delete []` the memory before knowing if `new []` will fail or not.

Comment: As Ardent said, it should be remembered that sizeof won't get the full size of the given array but the size of the type of the pointer isn't created locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to read to a pointer initialized with `nullptr` and you use `sizeof()` of that pointer when you have `length` data member. Since you already defined assignment operator for char array you can just use it:

```
istream& operator >> (istream& in, myString& other)
{
    char buffer[256];
    in.getline(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    other = buffer;
    return in;
}
```

note buffer size is arbitrary here, real application should handle different sizes and grow on need, but that would require more advanced string implementation than yours. For your simplified solution which looks like student task this could be fine.

Note: your `operator<<` also has issue, if you call it on default constructed object it would lead to UB, as `std::ostream` does not accept `nullptr` on `const char *`. Simple check for `nullptr` would be sufficient there:

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const myString& other)
{
    if(other.str)
        out << other.str;

    return out;
}
```

Ironically you did check for `nullptr` for `delete[]` which is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof(other.str)` is not the size of allocated buffer but the size of the pointer.

`other.str` is initialized to `nullptr` in the constructor, so it will try to read into invalid place and it will lead to Segmentation Fault.

Changing the constructor to

```
    myString()
    {
        str = new char[1];
        length = 0;
    }
```

to keep the buffer size always `length + 1` and changing the `operator>>` to

```
istream& operator >> (istream& in, myString& other)
{
    in.getline(other.str, other.length + 1);
    return in;
}
```

will prevent it from getting Segmentation Fault.

This won't solve the problem that the reading will be limited to length of already assigned string.
Improving the behavior will require other modifications like reading characters one-by-one and allocating buffer according to the size read.

Answer (score 0):

You do not allocate space for your data member `str` in the default constructor. So when you write

```
myString str_3;
cin >> str_3;
```

then your code in `operator>>` (i.e. `in.getline(other.str, sizeof(other.str));`) will write to memory that you did not allocate before).

Make sure that `str` provides enough allocated memory before writing to it, e.g. by using `alloc` or `realloc`.

Comment: With using cpp's coding ways, you shouldn't allocated or reallocated memory using C's functions. Instead reallocation should be using just copy to a temporary variable and copying it's data new allocated variable.

Comment: As this classes uses `delete[]` in destructor calling `alloc()` or `realloc()` would lead to UB